# How to get the parameter value from LWC when this parameters was passed from lightning record page

Tags: lightning-web-components, parameters, lightning-record-page

I want to pass a parameter value from a Lightning Record Page to LWC, but I did not get the parameter value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="key" type="String" label="key"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

```
export default class MessageFromKnowledge extends LightningElement {
    @api key;
    @track message;

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log(this.key); // this.key = undefiend
    }
  
}
```

[image]

I have fill in the "key" parameter in lightning record page. but the parameter is always undefined in lwc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no issues in the the code. It seems the property name `key` is a reserved keyword. Try with a different name.

Comment: Hi Saroj, Thank you very much, that's the root cause, I changed the property name and it works now.